# After Effects Canvas Slow Down Page

Tags: html5-canvas, after-effects

I made a map of my country(with 55 regions) in after affects.
Every region has an mouseover, mouseout and click event.
When mouseover a region, it scale to 1.2(tween animation) and on mouseout reset to normal.

I add this map on a slide of a slider and i notice a big slow down at performance.
The transition from one slide to another the transition is very slow.

Is this normal for this type of canvas?
Can i do something to improve performace?